# Retain rows in a dataframe based on 2 columns satisfying different criteria ranges; there are 27 rows of ranges in the dataframe

Tags: r, multiple-conditions, nested-for-loop, advanced-filter

Edited for better clarity:

I have a dataframe *dat* which I need to extract the entire row based on 2 columns *ut* and *ctz* which must satisfy their respective rows of ranges in data.frame *range_criteria* simultaneously; the ranges are different for *ut* and *ctz* and they **must satisfy their respective ranges**. If either the *ut* or *ctz* is out of the range, the entire row will be discarded.

In another words when checking to each row of criteria, *dat$ut* **must be equal OR within** *range_criteria$ut_min* to *range_criteria$ut_max* **AND** *dat$ctz* **must be equal OR within** *range_criteria$ctz_min* to *range_criteria$ctz_max*

I have been cracking my brain over this for for 12 hours, I must make sure each row of *ut* and *dat* is checked by **every row of the respective range_criteria**. I know I have to loop, but I am not sure how... please help!

```
dat <- data.frame(name = c("Asics", 'Tom', "Harry", "David", "Daniel", "Harri", "Davidi", "Daniely", "May", "Kelly"),
             ut = c(33, 2.4, 3.2, 3.5,9.5,5.2,6.0,45, 46, 51),
             ctz = c(7.3, 1, 6.0, 3.5, 5.1, 51.5, 6.6, 7, 9.1, 10.1))

range_criteria <- data.frame(ut_min = c(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 7.2, 9.0, 21.0),
    ut_max = c(5, 10, 15, 25, 30, 35, 50),
    ctz_min = c(0, 1, 2, 3.2, 4.3, 6.3, 6.9),
    ctz_max = c(5, 5.5, 6.1, 6.2, 6.4 ,6.5, 7.8))
```

The expected outcome should be:

```
interest <- data.frame(name = c('Asics', 'Tom', "David", "Daniely" , "May"),
                 ut = c(33, 2.4, 3.5,45, 46),
                 ctz = c(7.3, 1, 3.5, 7, 9.1))
```

Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it sounds like you want the `i`th row of `dat` to satisfy both ranges specified in the `i`th row of `range_criteria`, is that correct?

If so, there's no need to loop (explicitly). R's vectorized approach makes this work pretty easily:

```r
dat <- data.frame(name = c('Tom', "Harry", "David", "Daniel", "Harri", "Davidi", "Daniely"),
                  ut = c(2.4, 3.2, 3.5,9.5,5.2,6.0,45),
                  ctz = c(1, 6.0, 3.5, 5.1, 51.5, 6.6, 7))

rc <- data.frame(ut_min = c(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 7.2, 9.0, 21.0),
                             ut_max = c(5, 10, 15, 25, 30, 35, 50),
                             ctz_min = c(0, 1, 2, 3.2, 4.3, 6.3, 6.9),
                             ctz_max = c(5, 5.5, 6.1, 6.2, 6.4 ,6.5, 7.8))

dat[dat$ut >= rc$ut_min & dat$ut <= rc$ut_max & dat$ctz >= rc$ctz_min & dat$ctz <= rc$ctz_max,]
```

This also returns "Daniel" in addition to the other three names you mentioned, but looking at the data I think that's correct.

Alternately you could use a package designed for data manipulation like **dplyr** or **data.table** to do the same thing a bit more smoothly.

```r
library(data.table)

both <- cbind(dat, rc)
setDT(both)
interest <- both[between(ut, ut_min, ut_max) & between(ctz, ctz_min, ctz_max)]
```

or

```r
library(dplyr)

both <- bind_cols(dat, rc)

interest <- both %>%
  filter(ut >= ut_min & ut <= ut_max & ctz >= ctz_min & ctz <= ctz_max)
```

Comment: Hi NickCHK. Thank you for your reply! I miss out an important where the length of range_criteria is different from dat. I have made adjustment to the original. Could you please advise. Thanks!

Comment: If it's not that they line up, are you trying to get each row of the data to satisfy *every single one* of the criteria in the criteria table, or to satisfy *any one* of the criteria? If it's *every single one* then you really only have one criterion - above max(ut_min) and below min(ut_max), and the same for ctz, which nothing satisfies in your example data. If it's *any one* then I don't see why Harry doesn't qualify.

Comment: Hi NickCHK, hope I am not confusing you. There are two conditions to select the row: dat$ut must be >= range_criteria$ut_min **AND** < range_criteria$ut_max **WHILE** dat$ctz must be >= range_criteria$ctz_min **AND** < range_criteria$ctz_max. The range for range_criteria$ut_min : range_criteria$ut_max is different from range for range_criteria$ctz_min : range_criteria$ctz_max

Comment: What the answer I posted does is ensure that, for row i in the data and row j in the conditions, ut[i] >= ut_min[j] AND ut[i] <= ut_max[j] AND ctz[i] >= ctz_min[j] AND ctz[i] <= ctz_max[j]. Also in my answer, i = j at all times. From this, what needs to change? If the data and conditions have different numbers of rows, how do I pick j for a given i?